# All interface methods are unable to be overridden

Tags: java, jar

I've been at this for three days straight now, and I can't find an answer. Need some experienced people's advice. :)

We had a programmer leave us years back. All we have is a .jar file and no original source. So to make minor adjustments to this .jar I ran a decompiler and  inserted a class file of our own and modified one of the existing class files in the .jar to call it. It was an easy way to insert code we needed at a certain point in the application (this thing is huge so decompiling the entire project is a bit daunting and error prone). This all worked fine for the last couple years. However, last week I figured we needed a Thread to make things more efficiently...

The code completely craps out with no error as soon it hits the thread initialization. I further narrowed it down to the actual Runnable initialization and then down to seemingly any interface I try. Since I'm running within an existing jar file I have zero debug access other than writing to a log file of my own making. So I can write a log line before the Runnable initialization and then nothing comes after.

So a call to set a runnable variable:

```
Runnable r;
```

Seems fine so there is no problem with it finding the reference. However as soon as I try and overwrite the method:

```
r = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){

    }
};
```

The output to my log file below this line is never reached. So. I figured well maybe its an access modifier problem for whatever reason. So I checked it at runtime:

```
Method[] methods = Runnable.class.getDeclaredMethods();
for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    writeToLog("public method: " + methods[i]);
}
```

and I end up with:

"public method: public abstract void java.lang.Runnable.run()"

Which looks accessible to me...

Can anyone provide me with any insight as to WHY this could be failing? I'd assume this is some unchecked exception otherwise my try/catch around it should be outputting to my log. If only I had some ability to debug it. I even tried remote debugger options but it doesn't seem to output anything to it. Maybe there is some internal error handling in this jar that overrides everything. Maybe I've been working on this so long that I'm completely down the wrong path for figuring this out too!

All my code is ready to go I just need to stick it in a bloody Runnable! So frustrating :)  Thanks in advance!

**tldr:**  I'm inserting a class file into an existing jar because I don't have source access. All code runs fine but no interface methods can be overwritten (Runnable in particular) and I can't figure out why because I have no debug access either

**update**  Thanks to @mikibrv for the IntelliJ IDE suggestion. I now have an error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Any ideas why the class would not be defined when I can clearly find it and its public method?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Maven, you could try installing the JAR in your local maven repository and add it as a dependency to a project. Then you will be able to actually use the classes in a new project and extend them.

Like this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Also IDE's such as IntelliJ will be able to decompile the JAR for your for easy access. And even debug it

Another idea would be to take each class since you decompiled and recompile them again with a newer version of Java. Most probably the jar was compiled with an older version of Java.

Comment: It's true about the compiler version. It was a Java 6 build. However, for reasons out of my control I have to keep it as Java 6. I haven't heard of IntelliJ but I am downloading it now to give it a try. But in the meantime, can you think of the reason why a runnable initialization would fail like that? Is there some inherent java security I'm not aware of that is active from an already compiled .jar? I just don't get it.

Comment: @mikibrv Intellij for the win! Thanks for that advice. That IDE is epic. I never heard about it until now. I now at least have an error message:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. I have research to do... Any ideas on why this would be the error?

Comment: I am not sure how inserting a compiled class into a jar will work. Is it not possible for you to extend the class and use it like that? The question would actually be, how are you using that jar?